# List through XSLT

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

I have following set of codes for an XML list and I'm using the following XSLT to extract the content but it's not working. First and last are working fine but the middle one creating problem. Any help please.......

XML:

```
    <cl:sect1 identifier="ZQRRUG590702676" number="nonumber">
    <cl:complex-meta>
    <cl:title identifier="PLHOOC548347957">Questions for Review and Reflection</cl:title>
    </cl:complex-meta>
    <cl:quiz identifier="UUHXZX749864214">
    <cl:metadata-wrapper>
    <cl:descriptive-meta>
    <cl:broad-term>Chapter exercises</cl:broad-term>
    </cl:descriptive-meta>
    </cl:metadata-wrapper>
    <cl:question-section identifier="LMUGHP665075315">
    <cl:short-answer-section identifier="PDWZPT096484135">
    <cl:quiz-meta>
    <cl:numbering role="style" target-node="question">arabic</cl:numbering>
    </cl:quiz-meta>
    <cl:sa-item identifier="DHUJEX954944222">
<cl:question identifier="ZXPROB877164447"><cl:para identifier="UVPIYI046459379">Choose one of the theoretical perspectives on the family, and discuss how you might use it to understand something about life in <cl:style identifier="XWHGPG736884704" styles="italic">your</cl:style> family.</cl:para></cl:question>
    </cl:sa-item>
    <cl:sa-item identifier="XLIHNY049827846">
    <cl:question identifier="WBNMFT023816273"><cl:para identifier="MVVFTE506398129">Choose a magazine photo and analyze its content from one of the perspectives de-scribed in this chapter. Then analyze the photo from another theoretical perspective. How do your insights differ depending on which theoretical perspective is used?</cl:para></cl:question>
    </cl:sa-item>
    <cl:sa-item identifier="KHOISZ206843547">
    <cl:question identifier="YIRLTY425252173"><cl:para identifier="DEAOVV858913951">Discuss why science is often considered a better way to gain knowledge than is personal experience alone. When might this not be the case?</cl:para></cl:question>
    </cl:sa-item>
    <cl:sa-item identifier="UZUXJL108947882">
    <cl:question identifier="NOBHFC190777617"><cl:para identifier="CISHBM348415557">Think of a research topic, then review the data-gathering techniques described in this chapter to decide which of these you might use to investigate your topic.</cl:para></cl:question>
    </cl:sa-item>
    <cl:sa-item identifier="ZITOCE439682847">
    <cl:question identifier="MCRAPB388676722"><cl:para identifier="RTRSPD372632657"><cl:key-term-entry identifier="JTBDZT820091835"><cl:key-term identifier="VSNZVL072560329">Policy Question</cl:key-term></cl:key-term-entry>. What aspect of family life would it be helpful for policy makers to know more about as they make law and design social programs? How might this topic be researched? Is it controversial?</cl:para></cl:question>
    </cl:sa-item>
    </cl:short-answer-section>
    </cl:question-section>
    </cl:quiz>
    </cl:sect1>
```

XSLT:

```
<xsl:template match="cl:closer/cl:sect1/cl:quiz/cl:question-section/cl:short-answer-section/cl:sa-item[1]/cl:question[1]/cl:para">
                <xsl:element name="ParagraphStyleRange">
                    <xsl:attribute name="AppliedParagraphStyle">ParagraphStyle/EOCNLF</xsl:attribute>
                    <xsl:apply-templates/>
                </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="cl:closer/cl:sect1/cl:quiz/cl:question-section/cl:short-answer-section/cl:sa-item[not(position() = last())]/cl:question[not(position()=last())]/cl:para">
                <xsl:element name="ParagraphStyleRange">
                    <xsl:attribute name="AppliedParagraphStyle">ParagraphStyle/EOCNLM</xsl:attribute>
                    <xsl:apply-templates/>
                </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="cl:closer/cl:sect1/cl:quiz/cl:question-section/cl:short-answer-section/cl:sa-item[position()=last()]/cl:question[position()=last()]/cl:para">
                <xsl:element name="ParagraphStyleRange">
                    <xsl:attribute name="AppliedParagraphStyle">ParagraphStyle/EOCNLL</xsl:attribute>
                    <xsl:apply-templates/>
                </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All your `sa-item` elements have exactly one `question` child, therefore

```
cl:sa-item[not(position() = last())]/cl:question[not(position()=last())]
```

will never match anything (because within the `question` predicate both `position()` and `last()` will always be 1).  You probably just need to remove the predicate on the `question` step, i.e. have your templates check the index just of the `sa-item`, not also the `question` element.  The cleanest way to do this would be with priorities:

```
<xsl:template priority="3" match="cl:sa-item[1]/cl:question/cl:para">
  <!--...-->
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template priority="2" match="cl:sa-item[last()]/cl:question/cl:para">
  <!--...-->
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template priority="1" match="cl:sa-item/cl:question/cl:para">
  <!--...-->
</xsl:template>
```

This way, the first template will pick up the first `sa-item`, the second one will pick up the `last()` (assuming it is not *also* the first one, if the `short-answer-section` has only one item), and the third will pick up any others not consumed by the first two higher-priority templates.

Comment: @UmeshKahali glad it helped. On Stack Overflow the usual way to thank someone for a correct answer is to _accept_ it by clicking on the tick mark to the left of the answer (and you'll improve your own reputation score by doing this too).